# android custom View to bitmap

Tags: android, view, bitmap

I want to convert my own View to bitmap but it  didn't work

I mean to draw lines in my view

My Custom View Code:

```
public class PaintView extends View {

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;
private static final int TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP = 24;
private static final int BACKGROUND = 0xFFDDDDDD;
private List<Point> mPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
private int mLastPointIndex = 0;
private int mTouchTolerance;
private boolean isPathStarted = false;
private int x = 0;

public PaintView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    mTouchTolerance = dp2px(TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP);
    // readSDFile("myTest.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        if (i < 250) {
            Point p = new Point(i, i);
            mPoints.add(p);
        } else {
            Point p = new Point(i, 500 - i);
            mPoints.add(p);
        }

    }
}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    mTouchTolerance = dp2px(TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP);
    readSDFile("myTest.txt");
    // TODO just test points
    // Point p1 = new Point(20, 20);
    // Point p2 = new Point(100, 100);
    // Point p3 = new Point(200, 250);
    // Point p4 = new Point(280, 400);
    // Point p5 = new Point(350, 600);
    // Point p6 = new Point(400, 500);
    // mPoints.add(p1);
    // mPoints.add(p2);
    // mPoints.add(p3);
    // mPoints.add(p4);
    // mPoints.add(p5);
    // mPoints.add(p6);
}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    mTouchTolerance = dp2px(TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth,
        int oldHeight) {
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight);
    clear();

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(BACKGROUND);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    // // TODO remove if you dont want points to be drawn
    for (Point point : mPoints) {
        canvas.drawPoint(point.x, point.y, mPaint);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < mPoints.size(); i++) {
        mPath.moveTo(mPoints.get(i - 1).x, mPoints.get(i - 1).y);
        mPath.quadTo(mPoints.get(i - 1).x, mPoints.get(i - 1).y,
                mPoints.get(i).x, mPoints.get(i).y);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {

    if (checkPoint(x, y, mLastPointIndex)) {
        mPath.reset();
        // user starts from given point so path can beis started
        isPathStarted = true;
    } else {
        // user starts move from point which doen's belongs to mPinst list
        isPathStarted = false;
    }

}

// ADDED WITH LAST EDIT
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    // draw line with finger move
    if (isPathStarted) {
        mPath.reset();
        Point p = mPoints.get(mLastPointIndex);
        mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        mPath.lineTo(x, y);
    }
}

/**
 * Draws line.
 */
private void touch_up(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    if (checkPoint(x, y, mLastPointIndex + 1) && isPathStarted) {
        // move finished at valid point so draw whole line

        // start point
        Point p = mPoints.get(mLastPointIndex);
        mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        // end point
        p = mPoints.get(mLastPointIndex + 1);
        mPath.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
        // increment point index
        ++mLastPointIndex;
        isPathStarted = false;
    }

}

/**
 * Sets paint
 * 
 * @param paint
 */
public void setPaint(Paint paint) {
    this.mPaint = paint;
}

/**
 * Returns image as bitmap
 * 
 * @return
 */
public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return mBitmap;
}

/**
 * Clears canvas
 */
public void clear() {
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmap.eraseColor(BACKGROUND);
    mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Checks if user touch point with some tolerance
 */
private boolean checkPoint(float x, float y, int pointIndex) {
    if (pointIndex == mPoints.size()) {
        // out of bounds
        return false;
    }
    Point point = mPoints.get(pointIndex);
    // EDIT changed point.y to poin.x in the first if statement
    if (x > (point.x - mTouchTolerance) && x < (point.x + mTouchTolerance)) {
        if (y > (point.y - mTouchTolerance)
                && y < (point.y + mTouchTolerance)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public List<Point> getPoints() {
    return mPoints;
}

public void setPoints(List<Point> points) {
    this.mPoints = points;
}

private int dp2px(int dp) {
    Resources r = getContext().getResources();
    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
            r.getDisplayMetrics());
    return (int) px;

}}
```

My main Class Code:
I want to Set a bitmap in imageView,
and display it, but it didn't work Did i do something wrong?

```
public class LineTest extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View myView = new PaintView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_bitmap);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.display_img);
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(myView);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    // Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    // Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        // has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        // does not have background drawable, then draw white background on
        // the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    // return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: You created the view but did you attached it to your view hierarchy?

Comment: I didn't get you……could you tell me  more detailed point?

Comment: You're trying to get a bitmap representing a `View`, myView,  that you just create, it isn't attached to the view hierarchy. For your code to work you need to either have the view as a part of the view hierarchy or measure it yourself.

Comment: could you give some code example? you mean do something in xml? English is not my first language. so I can't get the meaning of " attached to the view hierarchy".